# Android - AJAX request doesn't work when APK is signed

Tags: android, ajax, eclipse, cordova

I am using eclipse to build my phonegap application and I have configured all the setting by referring Google and you tube. When I build my application in eclipse, by default its generate the apk in bin/res folder. For testing purpose, I have install that apk on my devices and its working well!! Even its working fine in eclipse emulator.

But when I generate the Keystore and sign the apk then the ajax request is not working properly. It executed the error as (jqXHR.status === 0). I can't figure out what is going wrong??

Comment: change the title of your question, so it will reflect what this question is all about, and will be searchable through search engines

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and jahroy has already edited the same. Please do provide your solution w.r.t above description. I'm messed up and dnt know what is gng wrong??

Comment: do you have access to the server side? is it SSL?

Comment: Yes...it's an SSL server. I got the access and point over here is I m making an ajax soap request to server and fetching the data...But surprisingly it doesn't work after signing an apk...